# DataTable First Row First Column taking default value on page load

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, icefaces, jsf-1.2

I have a List containing the employee details.

I am binding the datatable using the List as shown below:

```
<ice:dataTable id="dataExportTable"
                       var="employee"
                       value="#{dataExportData.employees}"
                       rows="5"
                       styleClass="dataPaginatorDataTable"
                       cellpadding="7">
                    <ice:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <ice:outputText id="column1"
                                            value="ID"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <ice:outputText id="number"
                                        value="#{employee.id}"/>
                    </ice:column>

                    <ice:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <ice:outputText id="column2"
                                            value="First Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <ice:outputText id="firstName"
                                        value="#{employee.firstName}"/>
                    </ice:column>

                    <ice:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <ice:outputText id="column3"
                                            value="Last Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <ice:outputText id="lastName"
                                        value="#{employee.lastName}"/>
                    </ice:column>

                    <ice:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <ice:outputText id="column4"
                                            value="Phone"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <ice:outputText id="phoneNo"
                                        value="#{employee.phoneNumber}"/>
                    </ice:column>
                </ice:dataTable>
```

All the values are displayed correctly in the datatable based on the employees except the first row first column value which is coming as 0 (i.e. the default value for an `int` member variable). I am using IceFaces 1.8.1 (jsf 1.2)

Kindly let me know where is the mistake :(

Comment: it seems that you are not populating your data correctly, i.e. you might not have set the id in mappings, maybe.

Comment: I have a drop-down in the same page. When a ValueChangeListener is triggered, it modifies some of the data displayed in the DataTable. At that time the first row first clumn data is displayed correctly, the problem appears only for the first time page load. Any pointers for resolving the issue?